# Calculating a voltage and power dissipated in a circuit after creating a supernode

Tags: power, voltage, current, kirchhoffs-laws

I am looking at [**this**](https://imgur.com/2bAXvCE) circuit and I am trying to calculate Vx and power supplied by the 1A source.

I believe my calculations for node V2 are correct but I am not too sure about my V1 and V3 supernode calculations. The answer I get for Vx is 1V which is not correct. The answer should be -12.4V. Also, the power supplied by the 1A source should be 31.76W, but I calculate (1A)(V1)=(1A)(77V)=77W, which is also incorrect. I would assume that I am making a big mistake with my supernode calculation to be getting values that are very different from what they should be?

I tried doing KCL for V1, V2, and V3 separately and I still get incorrect answers.
I get V1= 25V, V2= -15V, and V3=28V. So Vx=V2=-15V and I get Pdisipated=(V1)(1A)=(25V)(1A)=25W. Granted I am closer to the correct answers this time, but then again these are wrong.

[**Work for KCL at all three nodes**](https://imgur.com/XgHe7K3)

Comment: \$V_x=V_2/5\Omega\$? Nope, \$V_x=V_2\$, it's not a current. Furthermore, you can't add and substract different quantities, like \$-8[A]+2V_x+...\$. One is a current, \$2V_x\$ is a voltage!

Comment: So I went back and did K**C**L again for the three nodes and I get [**this**](http://imgur.com/5sx3vSM). Now, Vx would just be V2, correct? So that would make Vx -35V, which is incorrect as it should be -12.4V. Also, the power dissipated by the 1A source should be -27V * 1A = -27W, which is also incorrect. Power that is dissipated should always be positive. Why do you think I am getting these incorrect values, hryghr?

Comment: You are ignoring the current flowing through the VCVS in your first and third equations.

Answer (score 1):

Your equation for \$V_2\$ is correct, however, everything else seems to have errors. You mix up currents and voltages, be careful about that!

As \$V_2=V_x\$, I am only using \$V_x\$ from now on. I will use a coherent unit system of \$[V,A,\Omega]\$, so I won't use any unit notations.

For the middle node:
$$8+\frac{V_x-V_1}{8}+\frac{V_x}{5}=0$$
$$1)320-5V_1+13V_x=0$$

For the supernode:
$$8-\frac{V_3}{2}+1+\frac{V_x-V_1}{8}=0$$
$$2)\frac{V_x-V_1}{8}=\frac{V_3}{2}-9$$

And the relationship between \$V_1\$ and \$V_3\$:
$$3)V_3-2V_x=V_1$$

Using 1), 2) and 3), after some calculations you can determine the values of \$V_x, V_1\$ and \$V_3\$, and with that, the power supplied by the current source. I did the calculations and the given solutions are indeed correct.

Comment: hryghr, I tried to calculate V1, V2, and V3 using your three equations above with the help of [**WolframAlpha**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B8%2B%28%28%28x-320%29%2F%282%29%29%28-x%29%29%2F%288%29+%2B+%28%28%28x-320%29%2F%282%29%29%2F%285%29%29+%3D+0%5D+and+%5B8-%28%28z%29%2F%282%29%29%2B1%2B%28%284z-72%2Bx%29-x%29%2F%288%29%29%3D0%5D+and+%5Bz-2%28%28z-x%29%2F%282%29%29%3Dx%5D+%2C+solve+x%2Cy%2Cz) and I am unable to get the answers I am looking for. Am I inputting the equations incorrectly into WolframAlpha?

Comment: Most probably.  Be careful about every plus/minus sign.

Comment: Oops, looks like you just edited your equations a little bit. I re-did the calculation using your new equations in [**WolframAlpha**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5B8%2B%28%28y-x%29%2F%288%29%29%2B%28y%2F5%29%3D0%5D+and+%5B8-%28z%2F2%29%2B1%2B%28%28y-z%29%2F%288%29%29%3D0%5D+and+%5Bz-2y%3Dx%5D+) but the voltages are a little off. As you can see, V1=34.7V, V2=Vx=-11.27V.

Comment: Yes, I made some initial mistakes. Using this site I got the exact values: calculator.tutorvista.com/system-of-equations-solver.html

Comment: Do you see where I am going wrong with my input into WolframAlpha?

Comment: Second equation: it's (y-x)/8, not (y-z)/8.